# run java process without win 7 going into standy or hibernate or 

Tags: java, windows

I wondering if one could run java application for a long time e.g. 48 hrs, without windows halting it by going into some sleep mode (e.g., standby or hibernate or whatever). I need java to run without interruption until is finished, any ideas?

thanx

Comment: Why don't you just change the power settings? If you can't do that then look into SetThreadExecutionState().

Comment: Sample code in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/standbydetector.aspx?display=Mobile

Comment: I tired this code already, it doesn't work on a 64 bit machine, plus its an old VS 6 version.

Comment: It's Vista rather than 64 bit that breaks that Code Project link. What's wrong with SetThreadExecutionState()?

Comment: @Fuega oh, I see...Maybe you can try to detect `WM_POWERBROADCAST` event [How to prevent hibernate/suspend on a desktop in Vista](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/385c3b38-fb74-4bb8-b064-c2392c8f46d0/) using JNA version of `WndProc` in [Philipp Kursawe: OSGi Clipboard Monitor for Java on Windows using JNA](http://swik.net/Eclipse/Planet+Eclipse/Philipp+Kursawe%3a+OSGi+Clipboard+Monitor+for+Java+%28on+Windows+using+JNA%29/dofyr)...It looks interesting to try this myself :)

Comment: @David Heffernan Nice! we can use `Kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState()` using JNA as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247(v=vs.85).aspx (WM_POWERBROADCAST Message)

Answer (score 2):

Well as a direct hack , You can use [`Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to generate some key hit / mouse interrupt so that your machine won't goto idle mode

Comment: Nice hint. Did you already use that on a productive system, so you know it actually works?

Comment: @Lukas, No I wrote it tis Hack not the exact solution, and I didn't try it.

Comment: @David It will <!----------->

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> To prevent the system from
>   transitioning to a low-power state in
>   Windows Vista, an application must
>   call SetThreadExecutionState to inform
>   the system that it is in use.

This whole area of Windows changed drastically from XP to Vista so any solutions based on `WM_POWERBROADCAST` won't work on modern Windows.

So, the recommended solution is to call [`SetThreadExecutionState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  You could fake mouse messages using, e.g. `SendInput()` or some more Java native equivalent, but I'd probably go for `SetThreadExecutionState()`.